# Drupal 6 administer nodes permission is ignoring content type permissions

Tags: drupal, permissions, drupal-6

I'm needing to set different 'create content' permissions for different user roles. This only appears to work when a particular role has not been given the "administer node" permission. However, without this permission the role does not have permission to control whether or not the node is published (which I require) or to view the content management table (Home › Administer › Content management).

For example, I want a user role to be able to create new news items and to be able to publish/unpublish them, but not create new pages (but be able to edit existing pages).

Does anyone know a way around this? Or which permissions should be set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Administer Nodes permission gives more access than necessary, and some modules use it as a crutch permission since it exists.

You might want to switch off this permission and implement [Override Node Options](http://drupal.org/project/override_node_options) module which will let users publish unpublish content. These can work in conjunction with the create/edit/delete permissions at the content type level.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but do you know if this will allow those users to access the content management page? I'm being told that is essential.

Comment: Oh, no. Without Administer Nodes, you can't get to Edit. You can, however, recreate this page with Views and put it in the administrative Content (with exposed filters too). This is what I normally do so clients don't have too much access.

Comment: Also, you will need to make sure input filters are set correctly. Nodes that are Full HTML for example, roles will need access to that once they lose Administer Nodes.

Comment: Thanks for the great feedback. Personally I find this standard Drupal behaviour very frustrating as you'd think that if a user can edit some content then they should be able to view a list of that content!

Comment: Since discovered that the Content Management Filter module works without the administer nodes permission which gets round the content table issue.

Answer (score 0):

See the patch provided here http://drupal.org/node/214190 It looks like Drupal 7 may allow for this separation of permissions between publishing and full-blown administering, but for now you'll have to use the patch.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to install another module so I put this code in [hook_init()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_init/6) in one of our custom modules. Enforces the node/add page, by giving an access denied if the users do not have the "create *** content" permission.

```
  $arg = arg();
  // Quick hack to enforce node creation permissions.
  if (   $arg[0] == 'node'
      && !empty($arg[1])
      && $arg[1] == 'add'
      && !empty($arg[2])
        ) {
    $arg[2] = str_replace('-', '_', $arg[2]);
    if (!user_access('create ' . $arg[2] . ' content')) {
      drupal_access_denied();
    }
  }
```